# document.ready not working. No console errors and jQuery is included

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("li.on ul").attr("style", "display:block");
        jQuery("li.on").addClass("open");
    });
</script>
```

I typed '$' and 'jQuery' into the console to see if they're defined, and they are.
jQuery is added in the `<head>` tag. This script tag is add lower down in the HTML.

When I remove the jQuery(document).ready(function {... and just leave the two lines, my code works.

```
jQuery("li.on ul").attr("style", "display:block");
jQuery("li.on").addClass("open");
```

When I plug these two lines into the console, they work.

It only breaks when I add the .ready() function.

What's happening?

Comment: Can you show a jsfiddle.net or code snippet that reproduces?

Comment: Why would you do `.attr("style", "display:block");` instead of `.css("display","block");`?

Comment: Is your `script` tag in the `head` part of the HTML file? If yes, than it can help to put the `script` tag to the end of the file, just before the closing `</body>`.

Comment: @j08691 playing devils advocate... in case it had a style attribute already and you wanted to replace the entire contents? but yeah...

Comment: @cezar: `$(document).ready` should work.

Comment: Need to see an example the reproduces the issue. Otherwise I'd say you have an observation error.

Comment: Works here http://jsfiddle.net/qL8av6wa/ Can you provide some HTML as well?

Comment: I made a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1qpntyuy/ it works there. I'm assuming it's environmental? I had a problem like this on a different script tag earlier in the project.  I'm working with VS and ASP.NET framework if that helps at all

Comment: is this jsfiddle exactly like your code? I mean, do you have some javascript in your header. Maybe the code is crashing somewhere and stops execution or a never ending loop is executing. Also, can you just put an alert in your ready function see if it fires?

Comment: Any online link where this can be checked?

Comment: It looks like there's some more javascript that runs after my js that reverts the classes back. I also added my script tag right before the bottom of the body tag. Thanks for your help everyone! I can get it from here

Comment: are you referencing multiple jquery versions?

Comment: @bhed any clue ? recently, it had happened to me

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same issue "no blocks inside jQuery ready() function was firing while the JQuery library was loaded with no console errors"

Later, I came to notice that the end  tag was missing. Putting back the closing tag worked out for me.

```
So make sure, <script>...</script> tag exists
```